# bootstrap 3 rails 4 responsive navbar "icon-bar" not expanding

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When I shrink my page too much, or if I'm on a mobile device, my navbar turns into a little three lined button which is apparently called 'icon-bar'.  When I click, or touch this button nothing happens. This is problem exists for every platform, mobile, laptop etc...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
 </div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="div-navbar-thing">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <% if logged_in? && current_user.status == 'career/education' %>
      <% if current_user.username == 'Curry' %>
        <li><%= link_to 'Add skill', new_skill_path(@skill), class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <% end %>
      <li class='clearfix'><%= link_to 'References', references_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li class='clearfix'><%= link_to 'My Degree', courses_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li class='clearfix'><%= link_to 'logout',  logout_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li class='clearfix'><%= link_to 'Search Jobs',  jobs_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>




      <li class='clearfix'><%= link_to '#', class: 'navbar-brand dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown', "data-no-turbolink" => true do %>
        <%= current_user.username %> <span class='caret'></span>
      <% end %>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
          <li class='clearfix'> <%= link_to "My Profile", user_skill_path(current_user) %> </li>
          <li class='clearfix'> <%= link_to 'Edit My Profile', edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li class='clearfix'> <%= link_to 'My Library', user_skills_path(:id => current_user.id) %></li>
          <li class='clearfix'> <%= link_to 'My Docs/resumes',     resumes_path %></li>
        </ul>

      <li class='clearfix'><div class="btn-group nav_item">
      <%= link_to '#', class: 'navbar-brand', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown' do %>
      Earn Skills <span class='caret'></span>
    <% end %>         
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %>
          </li>
          <% end %>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'All Categories', skills_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <% elsif logged_in? && current_user.status == 'Employer' %>

      <li><%= link_to 'logout',  logout_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Post Job',  new_job_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'view/edit Jobs', job_path(:id => current_user.id), class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Search Users',  jobs_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%#= link_to 'Our Jobs',     job_path, %></li>
      <li><div class="btn-group nav_item">
      <%= link_to '#', class: 'navbar-brand', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown' do %>
      View Skills <span class='caret'></span>
    <% end %>         
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %>
          </li>
          <% end %>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'All Categories', skills_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <% else %>
      <li class='clearfix'><%= link_to 'log in',   login_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li class='clearfix'><%= link_to 'Register', new_user_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li class='clearfix'><div class="btn-group nav_item">
      <%= link_to '#', class: 'navbar-brand', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown' do %>
      Earn Skills <span class='caret'></span>
    <% end %>         
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
          <li class='clearfix'>
            <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %>
          </li>
          <% end %>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class='clearfix'><%= link_to 'All Categories', skills_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <% end %>
    <li class='navbar-brand'><font color="red"><strong>Beta</strong></font></li>
    <li class='clearfix'><%= link_to 'Give us Feedback', 'http://www.facebook.com/jetpackedu', :target => '_blank' %></li>


  </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

When I remove the class, the icon still stays there on mobile apps or if I shrink the page, but when the page gets shrunk to where the icon is there, no links are clickable. I'd like to either make the little 3 lined icon bar work, or just remove it all together.

Answer (score 1):

change your data-target to ".navbar-collapse"  I just saw this somewhere on S.O but can't find it. That should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have JavaScript enabled and the [collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) included? You can find a comment that looks like it may describe your issue in the [Bootstrap 3 Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), notably

> Requires JavaScript
>
> If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view the content within the .navbar-collapse.

as well as

> Plugin dependency
>
> The responsive navbar requires the [collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) to be included in your version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Okay thank you. I thought I had bootstrap installed, but apparently I didn't, I only had the navigation bar setup and a couple button classes. (which confuses me, is bootstrap installed or not?) I don't have any bootstrap files in my app, but I found the bootstrap.js file, however, I'm not sure where to put it in my rails app. Does it go in assets/javascripts?

Comment: I tried adding *= require_bootstrap  to my application.css.scss file and bootstrap.js  to my vendor/assets/javascripts folder and the navbar still isn't responsive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a a typo in the code

"#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"" for "#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"